# super() usage in multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I am new to python. I am trying to understand `super()` functionality in python multiple inheritance.

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ of B called")
        self.b = "B"

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ of C called")
        self.c = "C"

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ of D called")
        super().__init__()

    def output(self):
        print(self.b, self.c)

d = D()
d.output()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'D' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super()` will find the *next method in the MRO sequence*. This means that only *one* of the `__init__` methods in your base classes is going to be called.

You can inspect the MRO (the *Method Resolution Order*)  by looking at the [`__mro__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) of a class:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>)
```

so from `D`, the next class is `B`, followed by `C` and `object`. From `D.__init__()`, the `super().__init__()` expression will only call `B.__init__()`, and then because `C.__init__()` is *never called*, `self.c` is not set either.

You'll have to add more `super()` calls to your class implementations; it is safe to call `object.__init__()` with no arguments, so just use them *everywhere* here:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ of B called")
        super().__init__()
        self.b = "B"

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ of C called")
        super().__init__()
        self.c = "C"

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ of D called")
        super().__init__()

    def output(self):
        print(self.b, self.c)
```

Now `B.__init__` will invoke `C.__init__`, and `C.__init__` will call `object.__init__`, and calling `D().output()` works:

```
>>> d = D()
__init__ of D called
__init__ of B called
__init__ of C called
>>> d.output()
B C
```