# Python multiple inheritance - Method Resolution Order depending super() calls in parent clases?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

I've stumbled upon a somewhat confusing behaviour related to multiple inheritance. Consider the following setting:

```py
class Parent1:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"Hello from Parent1")


class Parent2:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"Hello from Parent2")


class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(f"Hello from Child")


c = Child()
```

I saw it already [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955731/super-usage-in-multiple-inheritance-in-python) that for all parent classes to be initialised, each of them should call the `object`'s `__init__` method too. I tried to include or omit the `super().__init__()` calls in the parent classes in different configurations to see how it actually works. The result was a bit confusing: it seems that in particular, I need to call `super` in the *first* parent class to have the *second* one initialised too. In other words, if I omit the `super()` call in Parent1 (and keep it or omit it in Parent2, no difference), only Parent1 is initialised. I'm just trying to understand *why* it is like that - especially considering that the Method Resolution Order doesn't actually seem to be affected; the output of `Child.mro()` was completely independent of the `super` calls:

```py
>>> Child.mro()
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent1'>, <class '__main__.Parent2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Even more surprisingly, even though Parent1 precedes Parent2 in MRO, it was always Parent2 that was getting initialised first (of course, in settings where both parent classes were initialised).

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. "I saw it already in another question that for all parent classes to be initialised, each of them should call the `object`'s `__init__` method too." The answer in that question doesn't state that each of them should call `object.__init__`... It  doesn't say that anywhere. In any case, of course you require `super()` in `Parent1`, how else do you expect `Parent2.__init__` to be called? "the output of Child.mro() was completely independent of the super calls:" Yes, of course. The `.mro()` isn't affected by that at all.

Comment: "Even more surprisingly, even though Parent1 precedes Parent2 in MRO, it was always Parent2 that was getting initialised first (of course, in settings where both parent classes were initialised)." Huh? In the code you've provided, the order of the calls is `Child.__init__`, `Parent1.__init__`, and finally `Parent2.__init__`... I think you are getting confused because you print *after* the call to super, put the print before.